# Understanding dstream.saveAsTextFiles() behavior

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I am working with spark streaming api to get familiarized with it. I am implementing a word count problem where I listen to a stream and find an accumulated word count after x-seconds and output it to text files. So after all transformations when I print the output to a file using the DStream's saveAsTextFiles() function I get odd output.

I am expecting it to create a text file after every x-seconds and dump latest results into that file. I am expecting the name of the file to be the prefix-timestamp-suffix as mentioned in documents. But instead what I get is a folder every x-seconds named what I expect the file to be named and inside that folder is part-* files with my results. Although they are correct but why is this happening? Is my expectation wrong somehow?

For transformation and stuff I am using this (in case anyone is curious):

```
# sort the dstream for current batch
sorted_counts = counts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False))

# get the top K values of each rdd from the transformed dstream
topK = sorted_counts.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.zipWithIndex().filter(<filter with big index>).map(<remove index here>))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your expectation is wrong.

Your calculation is executed on a cluster (multiple executors nodes). Each node works with some partition of dataset.
When you write data to file/s - each node dump its dataset to separate file under the same directory. That's how part-* appears.

Comment: I see. Thank you for clarifying. Appreciate it.